# How to play an mp4 video from server in android?

Tags: android, video, mp4

I am able to display a 3gp video from server. But when I tried to play an mp4 video it displayed an alert saying that Sorry,this video cannot be played. Please help me in this regard.

```
package com.play.video;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class PlayvideofromserverActivity extends Activity
{
    private VideoView vView;
    private String vSource;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        vView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vview);


        vView.requestFocus();


            vSource ="http://server.com/testvideo.mp4";
            vView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(vSource));


        vView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));


        vView.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on your server settings. Does your server allows mp4 MIMEType?

Comment: Are using an emulator to test ? If yes try on a device

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It help you.

```
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.setVideoPath(videoSource);
myVideoView.requestFocus();
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    myVideoView.start();
  }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Android doesn't always play mp4.**

> MP4 is just a container - the video and audio stream inside it will both be encoded in different formats.

`Android natively only supports certain types of formats.` There is a list here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Make sure the `video and audio encoding type is supported`. Just because it says "mp4" doesn't automatically mean it should be playable.

Credit goes to [Ken Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17399981/3496570)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);

String s=Common.videofilepath;
//Set the path of Video or URI
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(Common.videofilepath));

//Set the focus
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response...but what is Common in the above code?

Comment: Common.videofilepath = "httP//server.com/testvideo.mp4"