# Playing mp4 videos android app

Tags: android, video

I have a app that needs to play .mp4 videos.

Here is the code:

```
try
{
    videoView1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.Video1);
    video= Uri.parse("android.resource://dr.droid/" + R.raw.burn); 
    mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView1.setMediaController(mc);
    videoView1.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView1.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I always get an alert cannot play video, But I got no errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Try [this](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/using-videoview-to-play-mp4-from-sdcard.html)

Comment: @SpK I'm playing a video in my res/raw folder. I think the approach is different.

Comment: @SpK My bad. It really worked, I just need to change the path. Thanks! Sorry about what I just said.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31695815/3496570

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this -

```
String SrcPath = "/sdcard/Video/Android in Spaaaaaace!_low.mp4"; // Instead of this just give your raw folder path. 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
   myVideoView.setVideoPath(SrcPath);
   myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
   myVideoView.requestFocus();
   myVideoView.start();
}
```

Hope this will work.