# How to play .mp4 video in videoview in android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, mp4, android-videoview

I am working on a video player application, I want to play `.mp4` video in the native video view. I am not able to play video using a URL. I am getting the error "*Sorry this video cannot be played*" and I am also not able to play downloaded video in the native video view either.

My code for playing video in the video view:

```java
String mUrl = "http://www.servername.com/projects/projectname/videos/1361439400.mp4";

VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview)
videoMediaController = new MediaController(this);
mVideoView.setVideoPath(mUrl);
videoMediaController.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
mVideoView.setMediaController(videoMediaController);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

Comment: It's likely that that particular mp4 encoding is not supported. I answered in a seperate answer. To test you can try another mp4, for example this one works for me: http://archive.org/download/Pbtestfilemp4videotestmp4/video_test.mp4

Comment: i do the same but still i cant play .mp4 video 

08-12 14:37:30.599: D/MediaPlayer(23633): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
08-12 14:37:33.095: E/MediaPlayer(23633): error (1, -2147483648)
08-12 14:37:33.096: E/MediaPlayer(23633): Error (1,-2147483648)
08-12 14:37:33.096: D/VideoView(23633): Error: 1,-2147483648

got this error

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Finally it works for me.

```
private VideoView videoView;

videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.servername.com/projects/projectname/videos/1361439400.mp4");
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  @Override       
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       mp.setLooping(true);
       videoView.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: what is mp in above snippet??

Comment: Its an object of media player.

Comment: @HirenPatel But initially It shows a black screen.

Answer (score 31):

MP4 is just a container - the video and audio stream inside it will both be encoded in different formats.

Android natively only supports certain types of formats. [This is the list here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Make sure the video and audio encoding type is supported. Just because it says "mp4" doesn't automatically mean it should be playable.

Comment: so, how to know/set video encoding technique

Answer (score 23):

Use Like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL); //Declare your url here.

VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview)
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));       
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

Another Method:

```
  String LINK = "type_here_the_link";
  VideoView mVideoView  = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
  MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
  mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
  mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
  Uri video = Uri.parse(LINK);
  mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
  mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
  mVideoView.start();
```

If you are getting this error [Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side Error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832379/couldnt-open-file-on-client-side-trying-server-side-error-in-android). and also [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620049/how-to-play-video-from-url).
Hope this will give you some solution.

Comment: i do the same but still i cant play .mp4 video 08-12 14:37:30.599: D/MediaPlayer(23633): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side 08-12 14:37:33.095: E/MediaPlayer(23633): error (1, -2147483648) 08-12 14:37:33.096: E/MediaPlayer(23633): Error (1,-2147483648) 08-12 14:37:33.096: D/VideoView(23633): Error: 1,-2147483648 got this error

Comment: Error msg "Can't Play this video"

Answer (score 6):

Check the format of the video you are rendering.
Rendering of mp4 format started from API level 11
and the format must be mp4(H.264)

I encountered the same problem, I had to convert my video to many formats before I hit the format: Use total video converter to convert the video to mp4. It works like a charm.

Comment: i encounter the same problem i have to convert my video to many format before i hit the format: use total video converter to convert the video to mp4. trust me it works like charm

Comment: according to the android documentary mp4 is only supported from API Level 11 (Gingerbread)

Comment: Next time please edit you answer when you are enhancing it, rather than adding comments.  I have shifted one of the comments in for you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that is the problem but what worked for me is calling `mVideoView.start();` **inside** the `mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener` event callback.

For example:

```
Uri uriVideo = Uri.parse(<your link here>);

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(mContext);
mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uriVideo);
mVideoView.requestFocus();

mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
{
     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
     {
          mVideoView.start();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can do as

```
 val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoView)

       // If url is from raw
   /* val url = "android.resource://" + packageName
        .toString() + "/" + R.raw.video*/

    // If url is from network
    val url = "http://www.servername.com/projects/projectname/videos/1361439400.mp4"

    val video =
        Uri.parse(url)
    videoView.setVideoURI(video)
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener{
        videoView.start()
    }
```