# VideoView not showing video on all devices

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I am making an android app with a activity which contains a VideoView.

I have no such major issue with the VideoView but the VideoView is not showing video (only audio is playing) on some devices. On other devics both audio and video are showing up.

I am playing an .mp4 file stored in "/raw/mmm_movie_1.mp4"

Could you guyz please suggest some way by which I can play the video across all devices ? (I want to publish my app on the Play Store soon).

Secondly. I want the video to play full screen once i click on the VideoView.

How could I accomplish both the tasks? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this link.
[How to play .mp4 video in videoview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399351/how-to-play-mp4-video-in-videoview-in-android)

and yes full screen can be done by setting on click listener and and passing layout params width and hight to fill_parent