# My videoview says "cant play video" but webview can play that?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I use videoview to play some .gif but cant. when I use to play gif or mp4 I receive cant play video but when I try to use webview everything is ok.

```
VideoView i = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
i.setVideoPath("file:///android_asset/ad.gif");
i.start();
```

Comment: `gif` is **not** a video, therefore `VideoView` can't play it

Comment: As for mp4 - check the Android supported content encoding formats: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#video-codecs

Answer (score 0):

The current easiest way to get gifs to work outside of WebView is to use [the Glide library with ImageView](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
GlideApp.with(context).load("gif_source").into(imageView);
```

Edit: Didn't realise you also asked about MP4 (early morning). [Here's a post which gives some good info on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399351/how-to-play-mp4-video-in-videoview-in-android) as it can be quite complicated (things like making sure the MP4 is encoded in a format Android supports).

Comment: This will solve his problem with gifs, but not with the problem of not being able to play mp4 files.

Comment: Whoops didn't see the mp4 bit (early morning) I'll add a link to a post on how to do that now.

Comment: He can probably put a check of .gifs and .mp4 files and play it accordingly.